# Turn Off ReSharper Exception Browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015 which installed .NET 4.6 and ReSharper popped open the "Exception Browser" to alert me

> Unsupported FrameworkVersion 4.6

Now every time I open Visual Studio (2013) the ReSharper Exception Browser opens on top of it and won't allow me to get to the editor until I close out of the dialog. Sometimes there are exceptions, some times there aren't, either way it opens up.

It has now just become more of an annoyance than anything. Is there a way to

a.) Stop it from opening when there are no exceptions

or

b.) Turn if off completely

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I was using a "checked-build" (for debugging or diagnostic purposes) of ReSharper, used for . I was using **Build 8.2.3000.5195** which I had downloaded from the ReSharper website, so I'm not sure how I ended up with a checked-build, but once I installed **Build 8.2.3000.5176**, it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reason/solution. I was getting really annoyed with this "exception browser" for over a month now!